# Create a geotiff file with updated metadata tag without aux.xml file

Tags: python, metadata, gdal

I'm able to open a raster GeoTiff file and insert new tags in the associated metadata using python and Gdal. After updating the metadata a PAM (.aux.xml) file is created which contains the added information.

Is there a way using Python and/or Gdal to create a GeoTiff file which contains all the added metadata without being connected to the PAM file?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `GDAL_PAM_ENABLED` environment variable to `NO`:

https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#GDAL_PAM_ENABLED

In Python this can be done with:

```
import os
os.environ['GDAL_PAM_ENABLED'] = 'NO'
```

Note that this sets it only once, for the current Python session.

If, after setting, you calculate for example the histogram of a GeoTiff file, GDAL wont create an aux.xml file

`info = gdal.Info('somefile.tif', reportHistograms=True)`

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion but I got this error message:
 _band 1: SetCategoryNames() not supported for this dataset_

Comment: It might help if you make your question more specific. I can imagine errors when you try settings tags which the GeoTiff format doesn't support.